# NSMutableString Append Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have the following code that converts an array of strings to a string

```
-(NSString *) arrayToString:(NSMutableArray *) array {
    NSMutableString *strFinal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init ];

    for(int i =0; i < [array count]; i ++){
        NSLog(@"ARRAY STRING %@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
        [strFinal appendString:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return strFinal;
}
```

When I run the code it correctly appends the 20 or so strings retrieved from a server (they are substrings of a base64 encoded image string), but when I try and append them it only gives me the first and the last appended together?

Nslog returns the correct nsstring for each array element

Comment: Are you sure that all array objects are strings? You can check this using: `[[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`

Comment: What is the NSLog output?

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the need for your method entirely by using `NSArray`'s `componentsJoinedByString:` method:

```
NSString *result = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question *per se*, but you don't have to do this yourself.

[`NSArray -componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString%3a)

eg.

`strFinal = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, can you double check your input?

```
- (void)test
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three",nil];
    NSLog([self arrayToString:array]);
}

-(NSString *) arrayToString:(NSMutableArray *) array {
    NSMutableString *strFinal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init ];

    for(int i =0; i < [array count]; i ++){
        NSLog(@"ARRAY STRING %@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
        [strFinal appendString:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return strFinal;
}
```

NSLog

```
Rover[64422:907] ARRAY STRING one
Rover[64422:907] ARRAY STRING two
Rover[64422:907] ARRAY STRING three
Rover[64422:907] onetwothree
```

Comment: Could it be my input then? The strings are very large because it is a uiimage base64 encoded into a string?

Comment: Again the nslog works for the chunks of the base 64 string but the append does not work.